# Собрать и объяснить код (пример с сайта)

Tags: c++

Имееться код hash-алгоритма. Так как его надо исследовать, необходимо его запустить (для начала). Но он не компилируется. Код был найден [здесь](https://locklessinc.com/articles/crypto_hash/).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T, typename T_half, int size>

class double_uint
{
private:
    void fromstring(const std::string &s);
    std::string tostring(void) const;
public:
    T lo_, hi_;
    enum type_size
    {
        tsize = size,
        hsize = size / 2,
        qsize = size / 4
    };

    double_uint(const double_uint &u) : lo_(u.lo_), hi_(u.hi_) {}
    double_uint(const T_half &hi1, const T_half &hi2, const T_half &lo1, const T_half &lo2)
        : lo_(T(lo2) + (T(lo1) << qsize)),
          hi_(T(hi2) + (T(hi1) << qsize)) {}
    double_uint(const T &hi, const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_(hi) {}
    explicit double_uint(const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_() {}
    explicit double_uint(const std::string &s) {fromstring(s);};
    double_uint(void) : lo_(), hi_() {}

    /* Hack - basically we are a little-endian integer type */
    explicit double_uint(const unsigned char *c) {memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));}
    explicit double_uint(size_t len, const unsigned char *c)
    {
        if (len >= sizeof(*this))
        {
            memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(this, c, len);
            memset(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this) + len, 0, sizeof(*this) - len);
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const double_uint &x)
    {
        return o << std::string(x);
    }

    double_uint& operator= (int x)
    {
        lo_ = x;
        hi_ = T();
        return *this;
    }
    double_uint& operator=(const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ = u.lo_;
        hi_ = u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const {return lo_;}
    operator T() {return lo_;}
    operator const std::string() const {return tostring();}
    operator std::string() {return tostring();}

    double_uint operator+= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ += u.lo_;
        if (lo_ < old) hi_++;
        hi_ += u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator-= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ -= u.lo_;
        if (lo_ > old) hi_--;
        hi_ -= u.lo_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res += u;
    }

    double_uint operator- (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res -= u;
    }

    double_uint operator++ (void)
    {
        return *this += double_uint(1);
    }

    double_uint operator++ (int)
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        *this += double_uint(0, 1);
        return res;
    }

    double_uint operator- (void)
    {
        return double_uint(0) - *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (void) const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<<= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            hi_ = lo_ << (x - hsize);
            lo_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        hi_ <<= x;
        hi_ += lo_ >> (hsize - x);
        lo_ <<= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator>>= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            lo_ = hi_ >> (x - hsize);
            hi_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        lo_ >>= x;
        lo_ += hi_ << (hsize - x);
        hi_ >>= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<< (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res <<= x;
    }

    double_uint operator>> (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res >>= x;
    }

    static double_uint halfmul(T x, T y)
    {
        T_half x1, x2, y1, y2;
        x1 = x;
        x2 = x >> qsize;
        y1 = y;
        y2 = y >> qsize;

        T xx1(x1);
        T xx2(x2);
        T yy1(y1);
        T yy2(y2);

        double_uint p1, p2, p3, p4;
        p1.lo_ = xx1 * yy1;
        p2.lo_ = xx1 * yy2;
        p3.lo_ = xx2 * yy1;
        p4.lo_ = xx2 * yy2;

        p2 <<= qsize;
        p3 <<= qsize;
        p4 <<= hsize;
        return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
    }

    double_uint operator*= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        double_uint p1 = halfmul(lo_, u.lo_);
        double_uint p2 = halfmul(lo_, u.hi_);
        double_uint p3 = halfmul(hi_, u.lo_);

        p2 <<= hsize;
        p3 <<= hsize;
        return (*this = p1 + p2 + p3);
    }

    double_uint operator* (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res *= u;
    }

    double_uint operator^= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ ^= u.lo_;
        hi_ ^= u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator^ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res ^= u;
    }

    /* Calculates (self * u, folded in half) xor u */
    double_uint fold(const double_uint &u) const
    {
        typedef double_uint<double_uint, T, tsize * 2> Tdouble;

        Tdouble x(Tdouble::halfmul(*this, u));

        return x.lo_ ^ x.hi_;
    }
};

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
    std::string double_uint<T, T_half, size>::tostring(void) const
{
    int num = size / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    double_uint<T, T_half, size> v(*this);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v.lo_ & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
    void double_uint<T, T_half, size >::fromstring(const std::string &s)
{
    double_uint<T, T_half, size> temp;

    *this = 0;

    for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
    {
        if ((*i >= '0') && (*i <= '9'))
        {
            temp = *i - '0';
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'A') && (*i <= 'F'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'a') && (*i <= 'f'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid hex character\n");
        }

        *this <<= 4;
        *this += temp;
    }
}

static std::string tostring(const __uint128_t &x)
{
    int num = 128 / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    __uint128_t v(x);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const __uint128_t &x)
{
    return o << tostring(x);
}
typedef double_uint<__uint128_t, unsigned long long, 256> u256;
void hash_step(const u256 &i1, const u256 &i2, u256 &o1, u256 &o2)
{
    /*
     * Cube roots of primes.
     * (Square roots don't work as well when folded with zero.
     *  The high part becomes nearly all one bits.)
     *
     * They are scaled so that the uppermost bit is set.
     * Then the lowest bit is also set, so that the constant is odd
     */

    /* cbrt(2) */
    static const u256 t1(0xa14517cc6b945711, 0x1eed5b8adf128686,
                         0x144788148b18fde0, 0x30c00661b7d16e9d);

    /* cbrt(3) */
    static const u256 t2(0xb89ba24891f7b2e6, 0xef3f8b62b71933e0,
                         0x50c4a6157ab766cc, 0xfa2ba143e9029653);

    /* cbrt(5) */
    static const u256 t3(0xdae07de7f6269d97, 0xed0ddb59924b141a,
                         0x0ae36687aa58c29f, 0xe8293af2918f493b);

    /* cbrt(7) */
    static const u256 t4(0xf4daedd2c0c4edde, 0x50536bb743875dac,
                         0xfdb214852ccf272e, 0x53a3540f5e5aa011);

    /* cbrt(11) */
    static const u256 t5(0x8e55b096fcd22d4e, 0x3c1e6d4936833117,
                         0x0ae1a0b51ea515b2, 0x6ef98efb6ebf35e3);

    /* cbrt(13) */
    static const u256 t6(0x967c447c6d817406, 0x7bc5196b06dc9887,
                         0x214ac2f50046dc65, 0x0f9bfa326367aeb7);

    /* cbrt(17) */
    static const u256 t7(0xa48fe0a92bc653e6, 0xec03c7ed7e59981b,
                         0x3e3a27d8d8e54797, 0xd607fe20b08d6175);

    /* cbrt(19) */
    static const u256 t8(0xaac717b5769b6046, 0x27896d0e27f2c11e,
                         0x281e73be041f0383, 0xa937169045fb3849);

    /* cbrt(23) */
    static const u256 t9(0xb601eaa628c0c090, 0xac51900eab494a5c,
                         0x236edd364b4df8c4, 0x5a0cdaed7df05aed);

    o1 = i1;
    o2 = i2;

    o1 += (o2^t1).fold(t1);
    o2 += (o1^t2).fold(t2);
    o1 += (o2^t3).fold(t3);
    o2 += (o1^t4).fold(t4);
    o1 += (o2^t5).fold(t5);
    o2 += (o1^t6).fold(t6);
    o1 += (o2^t7).fold(t7);
    o2 += (o1^t8).fold(t8);
    o1 += (o2^t9).fold(t9);
}
```

Также хотелось бы получить объяснения самого кода.

Comment: А почему же вы сразу сообщение об ошибке не прикладываете?

Comment: 'u256' does not name a type

Comment: Скопируйте код полностью. В частности, `typedef`ы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, увы не работает.

Comment: код компилируется. [пруф](https://ideone.com/5ygQcL)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor,  я не могу понять что идет параметром функции, если в main вызвать hash_step (string);, где string - некая строка для хеширования выбивает ошибки. При этом на том сайте написано, что hash_step - сама хеш-функция, но само название говорит о функции шага. Не могли бы вы дописать эту часть кода, оформив его в ответ.

Comment: @MuscledBoy вот [так](https://ideone.com/1IvNyE) понятнее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот пример [рабочего кода](https://ideone.com/5qKs5B) с примерами как на числах, так и на строках, как вы и хотели.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename T_half, int size>

class double_uint
{
private:
    void fromstring(const std::string &s);
    std::string tostring(void) const;
public:
    T lo_, hi_;
    enum type_size
    {
        tsize = size,
        hsize = size / 2,
        qsize = size / 4
    };

    double_uint(const double_uint &u) : lo_(u.lo_), hi_(u.hi_) {}
    double_uint(const T_half &hi1, const T_half &hi2, const T_half &lo1, const T_half &lo2)
            : lo_(T(lo2) + (T(lo1) << qsize)),
              hi_(T(hi2) + (T(hi1) << qsize)) {}
    double_uint(const T &hi, const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_(hi) {}
    explicit double_uint(const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_() {}
    explicit double_uint(const std::string &s) {fromstring(s);};
    double_uint(void) : lo_(), hi_() {}

    /* Hack - basically we are a little-endian integer type */
    explicit double_uint(const unsigned char *c) {memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));}
    explicit double_uint(size_t len, const unsigned char *c)
    {
        if (len >= sizeof(*this))
        {
            memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(this, c, len);
            memset(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this) + len, 0, sizeof(*this) - len);
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const double_uint &x)
    {
        return o << std::string(x);
    }

    double_uint& operator= (int x)
    {
        lo_ = x;
        hi_ = T();
        return *this;
    }
    double_uint& operator=(const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ = u.lo_;
        hi_ = u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const {return lo_;}
    operator T() {return lo_;}
    operator const std::string() const {return tostring();}
    operator std::string() {return tostring();}

    double_uint operator+= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ += u.lo_;
        if (lo_ < old) hi_++;
        hi_ += u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator-= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ -= u.lo_;
        if (lo_ > old) hi_--;
        hi_ -= u.lo_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res += u;
    }

    double_uint operator- (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res -= u;
    }

    double_uint operator++ (void)
    {
        return *this += double_uint(1);
    }

    double_uint operator++ (int)
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        *this += double_uint(0, 1);
        return res;
    }

    double_uint operator- (void)
    {
        return double_uint(0) - *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (void) const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<<= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            hi_ = lo_ << (x - hsize);
            lo_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        hi_ <<= x;
        hi_ += lo_ >> (hsize - x);
        lo_ <<= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator>>= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            lo_ = hi_ >> (x - hsize);
            hi_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        lo_ >>= x;
        lo_ += hi_ << (hsize - x);
        hi_ >>= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<< (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res <<= x;
    }

    double_uint operator>> (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res >>= x;
    }

    static double_uint halfmul(T x, T y)
    {
        T_half x1, x2, y1, y2;
        x1 = x;
        x2 = x >> qsize;
        y1 = y;
        y2 = y >> qsize;

        T xx1(x1);
        T xx2(x2);
        T yy1(y1);
        T yy2(y2);

        double_uint p1, p2, p3, p4;
        p1.lo_ = xx1 * yy1;
        p2.lo_ = xx1 * yy2;
        p3.lo_ = xx2 * yy1;
        p4.lo_ = xx2 * yy2;

        p2 <<= qsize;
        p3 <<= qsize;
        p4 <<= hsize;
        return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
    }

    double_uint operator*= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        double_uint p1 = halfmul(lo_, u.lo_);
        double_uint p2 = halfmul(lo_, u.hi_);
        double_uint p3 = halfmul(hi_, u.lo_);

        p2 <<= hsize;
        p3 <<= hsize;
        return (*this = p1 + p2 + p3);
    }

    double_uint operator* (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res *= u;
    }

    double_uint operator^= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ ^= u.lo_;
        hi_ ^= u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator^ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res ^= u;
    }

    /* Calculates (self * u, folded in half) xor u */
    double_uint fold(const double_uint &u) const
    {
        typedef double_uint<double_uint, T, tsize * 2> Tdouble;

        Tdouble x(Tdouble::halfmul(*this, u));

        return x.lo_ ^ x.hi_;
    }
};

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
std::string double_uint<T, T_half, size>::tostring(void) const
{
    int num = size / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    double_uint<T, T_half, size> v(*this);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v.lo_ & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
void double_uint<T, T_half, size >::fromstring(const std::string &s)
{
    double_uint<T, T_half, size> temp;

    *this = 0;

    for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
    {
        if ((*i >= '0') && (*i <= '9'))
        {
            temp = *i - '0';
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'A') && (*i <= 'F'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'a') && (*i <= 'f'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid hex character\n");
        }

        *this <<= 4;
        *this += temp;
    }
}

static std::string tostring(const __uint128_t &x)
{
    int num = 128 / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    __uint128_t v(x);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const __uint128_t &x)
{
    return o << tostring(x);
}
typedef double_uint<__uint128_t, unsigned long long, 256> u256;
void hash_step(const u256 &i1, const u256 &i2, u256 &o1, u256 &o2)
{
    /*
     * Cube roots of primes.
     * (Square roots don't work as well when folded with zero.
     *  The high part becomes nearly all one bits.)
     *
     * They are scaled so that the uppermost bit is set.
     * Then the lowest bit is also set, so that the constant is odd
     */

    /* cbrt(2) */
    static const u256 t1(0xa14517cc6b945711, 0x1eed5b8adf128686,
                         0x144788148b18fde0, 0x30c00661b7d16e9d);

    /* cbrt(3) */
    static const u256 t2(0xb89ba24891f7b2e6, 0xef3f8b62b71933e0,
                         0x50c4a6157ab766cc, 0xfa2ba143e9029653);

    /* cbrt(5) */
    static const u256 t3(0xdae07de7f6269d97, 0xed0ddb59924b141a,
                         0x0ae36687aa58c29f, 0xe8293af2918f493b);

    /* cbrt(7) */
    static const u256 t4(0xf4daedd2c0c4edde, 0x50536bb743875dac,
                         0xfdb214852ccf272e, 0x53a3540f5e5aa011);

    /* cbrt(11) */
    static const u256 t5(0x8e55b096fcd22d4e, 0x3c1e6d4936833117,
                         0x0ae1a0b51ea515b2, 0x6ef98efb6ebf35e3);

    /* cbrt(13) */
    static const u256 t6(0x967c447c6d817406, 0x7bc5196b06dc9887,
                         0x214ac2f50046dc65, 0x0f9bfa326367aeb7);

    /* cbrt(17) */
    static const u256 t7(0xa48fe0a92bc653e6, 0xec03c7ed7e59981b,
                         0x3e3a27d8d8e54797, 0xd607fe20b08d6175);

    /* cbrt(19) */
    static const u256 t8(0xaac717b5769b6046, 0x27896d0e27f2c11e,
                         0x281e73be041f0383, 0xa937169045fb3849);

    /* cbrt(23) */
    static const u256 t9(0xb601eaa628c0c090, 0xac51900eab494a5c,
                         0x236edd364b4df8c4, 0x5a0cdaed7df05aed);

    o1 = i1;
    o2 = i2;

    o1 += (o2^t1).fold(t1);
    o2 += (o1^t2).fold(t2);
    o1 += (o2^t3).fold(t3);
    o2 += (o1^t4).fold(t4);
    o1 += (o2^t5).fold(t5);
    o2 += (o1^t6).fold(t6);
    o1 += (o2^t7).fold(t7);
    o2 += (o1^t8).fold(t8);
    o1 += (o2^t9).fold(t9);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;


    u256 *ll1 = new u256('sd', 'asd', 'sdad', 'dsa');
    u256 *ll2 = new u256(50000000, 6000000, 7000000, 8000000);
    u256 *ll3 = new u256(9000000000, 10000000000, 11000000000, 12000000000);
    u256 *ll4 = new u256(13000000000000000000, 14000000000000000000, 15000000000000000000, 16000000000000000000);

    hash_step(*ll1, *ll2, *ll3, *ll4);
    cout << tostring(ll1->lo_) << " : " << tostring(ll1->hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(ll2->lo_) << " : " << tostring(ll2->hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(ll3->lo_) << " : " << tostring(ll3->hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(ll4->lo_) << " : " << tostring(ll4->hi_) << endl << endl << endl;


    u256 str1 = (const u256 &) "Blue";
    u256 str2 = (const u256 &) "Red";
    u256 str3 = (const u256 &) "Orange";
    u256 str4 = (const u256 &) "Yellow";
    hash_step(str1, str2, str3, str4);
    cout << tostring(str1.lo_) << " : " << tostring(str1.hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(str2.lo_) << " : " << tostring(str2.hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(str3.lo_) << " : " << tostring(str3.hi_) << endl;
    cout << tostring(str4.lo_) << " : " << tostring(str4.hi_) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дерзну спросить Вас, могли бы вы написать коментарии к коду (с C++ практически дела не имел). Более чем уверен, что не захотите, но все же. Тогда забирете 100 балов. Вам от них проку мало, но, возможно ради тренировки и опыта.

Comment: ко всему коду или  какие моменты вам непоняты(если их несколько)?

Comment: ко всему коду желательно, каждый метод и класс. К тому же, что такое "Blue", "Red",... Если я правильно понимаю, вы в качестве примера мспользуете строку "Hello, World!", тогда для чего нужны цвета? Предпочтительно было бы знать за что отвечают все методы и классы, что бы понять суть алгоритма.

Comment: более того, данный алгоритм есть уникальным в своем роде? На сайте с исходником выложен кастомный вариант, ведь так?

Comment: "Blue", "Red" - это просто произвольные строки. про уникальность не знаю. Hello, World - просто забыл удалить

Answer (score 1):

добавьте определение перед использованием

```
typedef double_uint<__uint128_t, unsigned long long, 256> u256;
```

Comment: добавил, но: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: могу ли я вас попросить собрать код, если для вас не составит труда?

Comment: возможно, я не так что-то делаю

Comment: @ Muscled Boy, извените, но  не могу - есть желание помочь, но делать за кого то то, что самому неинтересно, непринесет пользу ни мне ни вам.  У меня и время для этого сайта едва хватает, чтоб быстро прочитать пару вопросов  и быстро написать ответ ( если знаю конечно ).

Comment: @MuscledBoy Это пример кода, причем сам требуемый алгоритм, это функция hash_step, все остальное это класс, который обеспечивает работу с 256 битными значениями как с обычными переменными. И тут есть только эта функция. А в законченной программе на C++ должна быть функция main() с которой собственно начинается работа приложения. Вам надо самому ее написать и вызывать из нее то что посчитаете нужным для анализа

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

typedef double_uint<__uint128_t, unsigned long long, 256> u256;

template <typename T, typename T_half, int size>

class double_uint
{
private:
    void fromstring(const std::string &s);
    std::string tostring(void) const;
public:
    T lo_, hi_;
    enum type_size
    {
        tsize = size,
        hsize = size / 2,
        qsize = size / 4
    };

    double_uint(const double_uint &u) : lo_(u.lo_), hi_(u.hi_) {}
    double_uint(const T_half &hi1, const T_half &hi2, const T_half &lo1, const T_half &lo2)
        : lo_(T(lo2) + (T(lo1) << qsize)),
          hi_(T(hi2) + (T(hi1) << qsize)) {}
    double_uint(const T &hi, const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_(hi) {}
    explicit double_uint(const T &lo) : lo_(lo), hi_() {}
    explicit double_uint(const std::string &s) {fromstring(s);};
    double_uint(void) : lo_(), hi_() {}

    /* Hack - basically we are a little-endian integer type */
    explicit double_uint(const unsigned char *c) {memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));}
    explicit double_uint(size_t len, const unsigned char *c)
    {
        if (len >= sizeof(*this))
        {
            memcpy(this, c, sizeof(*this));
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(this, c, len);
            memset(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(this) + len, 0, sizeof(*this) - len);
        }
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const double_uint &x)
    {
        return o << std::string(x);
    }

    double_uint& operator= (int x)
    {
        lo_ = x;
        hi_ = T();
        return *this;
    }
    double_uint& operator=(const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ = u.lo_;
        hi_ = u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const {return lo_;}
    operator T() {return lo_;}
    operator const std::string() const {return tostring();}
    operator std::string() {return tostring();}

    double_uint operator+= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ += u.lo_;
        if (lo_ < old) hi_++;
        hi_ += u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator-= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        T old = lo_;
        lo_ -= u.lo_;
        if (lo_ > old) hi_--;
        hi_ -= u.lo_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res += u;
    }

    double_uint operator- (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res -= u;
    }

    double_uint operator++ (void)
    {
        return *this += double_uint(1);
    }

    double_uint operator++ (int)
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        *this += double_uint(0, 1);
        return res;
    }

    double_uint operator- (void)
    {
        return double_uint(0) - *this;
    }

    double_uint operator+ (void) const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<<= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            hi_ = lo_ << (x - hsize);
            lo_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        hi_ <<= x;
        hi_ += lo_ >> (hsize - x);
        lo_ <<= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator>>= (int x)
    {
        x &= (tsize - 1);
        if (x >= hsize)
        {
            lo_ = hi_ >> (x - hsize);
            hi_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }

        lo_ >>= x;
        lo_ += hi_ << (hsize - x);
        hi_ >>= x;

        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator<< (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res <<= x;
    }

    double_uint operator>> (int x) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res >>= x;
    }

    static double_uint halfmul(T x, T y)
    {
        T_half x1, x2, y1, y2;
        x1 = x;
        x2 = x >> qsize;
        y1 = y;
        y2 = y >> qsize;

        T xx1(x1);
        T xx2(x2);
        T yy1(y1);
        T yy2(y2);

        double_uint p1, p2, p3, p4;
        p1.lo_ = xx1 * yy1;
        p2.lo_ = xx1 * yy2;
        p3.lo_ = xx2 * yy1;
        p4.lo_ = xx2 * yy2;

        p2 <<= qsize;
        p3 <<= qsize;
        p4 <<= hsize;
        return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
    }

    double_uint operator*= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        double_uint p1 = halfmul(lo_, u.lo_);
        double_uint p2 = halfmul(lo_, u.hi_);
        double_uint p3 = halfmul(hi_, u.lo_);

        p2 <<= hsize;
        p3 <<= hsize;
        return (*this = p1 + p2 + p3);
    }

    double_uint operator* (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res *= u;
    }

    double_uint operator^= (const double_uint &u)
    {
        lo_ ^= u.lo_;
        hi_ ^= u.hi_;
        return *this;
    }

    double_uint operator^ (const double_uint &u) const
    {
        double_uint res(*this);
        return res ^= u;
    }

    /* Calculates (self * u, folded in half) xor u */
    double_uint fold(const double_uint &u) const
    {
        typedef double_uint<double_uint, T, tsize * 2> Tdouble;

        Tdouble x(Tdouble::halfmul(*this, u));

        return x.lo_ ^ x.hi_;
    }
};

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
    std::string double_uint<T, T_half, size>::tostring(void) const
{
    int num = size / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    double_uint<T, T_half, size> v(*this);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v.lo_ & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

template <class T, class T_half, int size>
    void double_uint<T, T_half, size >::fromstring(const std::string &s)
{
    double_uint<T, T_half, size> temp;

    *this = 0;

    for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
    {
        if ((*i >= '0') && (*i <= '9'))
        {
            temp = *i - '0';
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'A') && (*i <= 'F'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'a') && (*i <= 'f'))
        {
            temp = *i - 'A' + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid hex character\n");
        }

        *this <<= 4;
        *this += temp;
    }
}

static std::string tostring(const __uint128_t &x)
{
    int num = 128 / 4;

    static const char hex_symb[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    /* Pad with zeros */
    std::string s(num, '0');

    __uint128_t v(x);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s[i] = hex_symb[v & 0xf];
        v >>= 4;
    }

    return s;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const __uint128_t &x)
{
    return o << tostring(x);
}

void hash_step(const u256 &i1, const u256 &i2, u256 &o1, u256 &o2)
{
    /*
     * Cube roots of primes.
     * (Square roots don't work as well when folded with zero.
     *  The high part becomes nearly all one bits.)
     *
     * They are scaled so that the uppermost bit is set.
     * Then the lowest bit is also set, so that the constant is odd
     */

    /* cbrt(2) */
    static const u256 t1(0xa14517cc6b945711, 0x1eed5b8adf128686,
                         0x144788148b18fde0, 0x30c00661b7d16e9d);

    /* cbrt(3) */
    static const u256 t2(0xb89ba24891f7b2e6, 0xef3f8b62b71933e0,
                         0x50c4a6157ab766cc, 0xfa2ba143e9029653);

    /* cbrt(5) */
    static const u256 t3(0xdae07de7f6269d97, 0xed0ddb59924b141a,
                         0x0ae36687aa58c29f, 0xe8293af2918f493b);

    /* cbrt(7) */
    static const u256 t4(0xf4daedd2c0c4edde, 0x50536bb743875dac,
                         0xfdb214852ccf272e, 0x53a3540f5e5aa011);

    /* cbrt(11) */
    static const u256 t5(0x8e55b096fcd22d4e, 0x3c1e6d4936833117,
                         0x0ae1a0b51ea515b2, 0x6ef98efb6ebf35e3);

    /* cbrt(13) */
    static const u256 t6(0x967c447c6d817406, 0x7bc5196b06dc9887,
                         0x214ac2f50046dc65, 0x0f9bfa326367aeb7);

    /* cbrt(17) */
    static const u256 t7(0xa48fe0a92bc653e6, 0xec03c7ed7e59981b,
                         0x3e3a27d8d8e54797, 0xd607fe20b08d6175);

    /* cbrt(19) */
    static const u256 t8(0xaac717b5769b6046, 0x27896d0e27f2c11e,
                         0x281e73be041f0383, 0xa937169045fb3849);

    /* cbrt(23) */
    static const u256 t9(0xb601eaa628c0c090, 0xac51900eab494a5c,
                         0x236edd364b4df8c4, 0x5a0cdaed7df05aed);

    o1 = i1;
    o2 = i2;

    o1 += (o2^t1).fold(t1);
    o2 += (o1^t2).fold(t2);
    o1 += (o2^t3).fold(t3);
    o2 += (o1^t4).fold(t4);
    o1 += (o2^t5).fold(t5);
    o2 += (o1^t6).fold(t6);
    o1 += (o2^t7).fold(t7);
    o2 += (o1^t8).fold(t8);
    o1 += (o2^t9).fold(t9);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: только main добавили?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor main и typedef u256. Насколько я понимаю, ошибки у него только в этом, а сам он собрать код не может

Comment: вы 2 раза определили u256

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, допишите ответ. Я хотел увидеть как работает код: в main создать какой-то char str[]="abc"; и вызвать hash_step (str); , но меня смущает тот момент, что hash_step - не сама хеширующая функция. Это видимо функция для шага.

Comment: @MuscledBoy Вообще то это сама хеширующая функция. только считающая хеш для одного блока. если длина входного сообщения больше одного блока, то каждый блок обрабатывается этой функцией отдельно и ей наверняка в качестве значений внутренних переменных при этом передаются результаты обработки предыдущего блока. это надо смотреть в текстовом описании полного алгоритма. ибо в этом коде нет частей отвечающих за это.

Comment: @MuscledBoy И да, для оценки качества алгоритма хеширования достаточно рассмотрения одного "шага", т.е. обработки одного блока

Comment: @Mike, спасибо.