# создание нового типа данных

Tags: c++

Хочу создать новый тип данных long long long double, чтобы занимал 32 байта. Для длиннющих-предлиннющих циферок :3

Нашел, типы данных, определяемые пользователем в C++ (создание новых типов данных) но по сути, это обрезание функционала фундаментальных типов данных. 
А как нарастить функционал ???

пишу такой код, но он выдает ошибку компилятора C2150. (Visual Studio 2010)

```
   struct Svoe_chislo
   {
     double Perem : 32;
   };
```

Comment: Во-первых, число после `:` - это биты, а не байты. Во-вторых, это применимо только к целочисленными типам. В-третьих, нарастить количество битов в типе нельзя.

Comment: Ну кстати тут недавно был конкурсный вопрос, где в исходнике была реализация длинного числа (целого беззнакового, правда) Может, пригодится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790596/286405

Answer (score 2):

В C++ есть определенный набор "встроенных" типов:

```
bool
char 
int
float 
double
void 
wchar_t
```

Вы не можете изменит их размер.

Если вы хотите создать новый тип, то можете объявить структуру, скажем, `super_long_double`, которая будет хранить 32 байта (`char[32]`), и добавить перегрузки нужных вам операторов для этой структуры - будь то плюс, минус и тд.

Ну например:

```
// Ваша структура
struct super_long_double {
    // Данные (32 байта)
    char data[32];    

    // Конструктор по-умолчанию (инициализируйте тут ваш тип)
    super_long_double() { /* Тут логика */ }

    // Конструктор, принимающий double. Для удобной инициализации
    super_long_double(double value) { /* И тут логика */ }

    // Оператор суммы
    super_long_double operator+(const super_long_double &rhl) {
        super_long_double result;
        // Тут логика сложения
        return result;
    }

   // Оператор типа double, для удобного выведения в консоль
    operator double() const {
        // Вернуть какое-то значение
        return 0.31512345;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Удобная инициализация (см. 2 конструктор)
    super_long_double s = 0.21412;
    super_long_double d;
    // Вывод в консоль 
    // (неявное приведение суммы к double, см. operator double)
    cout << (s + d) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Так как операции над `double`, `long` и прочими типами описаны в стандартах, и в большинстве случаев поддерживаются (или ускоряются, как вам будет угодно) процессором, то вы **не можете просто взять и расширить существующий тип**.

Если вы определяете свой тип так, как я показал, то вам придется **для каждой** арифметической (а может, и не только) **операции писать собственную логику**. И такие операции, увы, будут производится не в одно, а в несколько, может несколько десятков операций, т.е. операции с такими типами **будут производиться в разы дольше**.

Поэтому использовать такой подход стоит **лишь тогда**, когда вам нужно, к примеру, сделать тип с запятой для каких-то вычислений, связанных с деньгами (чтобы не потерять мелочь), ну или же когда вам нужно считать **огроооооомные** числа, что не помещаются в встроенные типы.

Но тогда возникает другой вопрос - **а все ли вы делаете правильно?**

Comment: Почему операции будут производиться дольше? Можно ли ускорить, если сделать asm вставки? Тогда в теории будет быстрее? Например, если стоит задача реализовать тип Decimal в С++ (точное число с запятой в C#)

Comment: дольше потому что это будет не одна операция над примитивом, а несколько операций над несколькими примитивами. Ваш decimal в простейшем случае можно реализовать массивом char. Работаете с ним побитно, сложение, вычитание итд придется написать руками. Это будет долго. Говорите, что после запятой есть 10 знаков - вот и decimal. asm вставки - самое последнее дело, ибо очень зависят от компилятора и платформы. Можно порыться в различных sse/avx инструкциях, для них обычно в компиляторах уже есть intrinsic'и - что-то вроде макросов, которые разворачиваются в ассемблерные инструкции.

Comment: Но вообще, любой хороший код на плюсах, собранный свежим компилятором с включенной поддержкой соответствующих инструкций и оптимизаций, будет и так достаточно оптимальным